# stsadm crash after sps07 to sps10 upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

I have made an upgrade from sps07 to sps10 and I am trying now to make backups of sps10 using the command

```
stsadm -o backup -directory c:\backup -backupmethod full
```

The problem that Occurs is that stsadm crashes when trying todo the backup. Even worse is that when I try just to start stsadm from the command line I get following error.

`Unhanded exception: System.MissingMethodException: Methode not found: "Void` `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.Dispose()".at` `Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin.Main(String[] args)`

Holy moly what is happening?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with what Robert says - STSADM should still run on 2010, it is just deprecated. (This is to help with the migration from STSADM stuff to Powershell based stuff.)

My guess is that you are still running the 2007 version of STSADM. I copied a 2007 version of STSADM to a (fresh) 2010 server, and got the exact same error as you.

Are you going directly to `program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\bin` to run STSADM? Or do you have the hive setup in your `PATH` environment variable (or in a batch script, or something else that would set it automatically?) Check to make sure that you are going to `\14\bin` and not `\12\bin`

Comment: You where right! I have a Backup script which runs the stsadm command by calling the depraceted path. I had to change it like you said to \12\bin

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint 2010, you should switch from STSADM to PowerShell.  The following link to TechNet shows the mappings between STSADM commands and PowerShell.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621084.aspx